# When computation takes a long time, how to find out if this is normal or if my script contains an error?

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, code-review

I study mechanical engineering and I' working on my first bigger project on Mathematica right now. It's a multibody problem that leads to a **system of 4 large equations** I'm supposed to solve symbolically. Mathematica is running for about an hour now, but didn't finish so far and I have no idea if I should let it continue or cancel and look for an error in the script (already looked for one very thoroughly without success, but of course it's possible I missed something).

**Are there any tricks I can use** to find out if there's an error in the script that keeps Mathematica from finding the solution?

If anyone wants to have a look at the precise file in question, [here it is](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1coAZpzMbr8x4nwYl3MwxsfI1sBb_YiJe). Everything works out for me except the very last step that contains the `Solve[...]`.

Comment: @Somos Changed the download to Google Drive, I think you don't need an account there?

Comment: @Somos As for the solvability, theoretically the resulting system should always be solveable, except I made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: Okay, I got the Notebook running except the `Solve[]`. A quick check indicates that the four equations are linear in the four variables you are solving for. Mathematica has no problem solving linear equations, **but** the coefficients are lengthy expressions and the solution is unlikely to simplify.

Comment: @Somos They don't need to simplify, they will be put into Matlab to solve numerically. This approach is mandatory and can't change. So if I get something like ´x''[t]= WHATEVERCOMPLICATEDSTUFF´ I'm happy for here.

Comment: As I suspected. You need to let  Matlab solve the system numerically.

Comment: @Somos Yeah, but it's also mandatory for the project to use Mathematica to get the x''[t]=something. I think it's because Matlab ode45 can only deal with systems of first order ODEs.

Comment: In symbolic calculations, most of the time is spent solving equations and simplifying solutions. I use a time limit for example `Simplify[expr, TimeConstraint -> 1]` and `TimeConstrained[expr,t]`

Comment: The link gives me a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, the problem was a single `//FullSimplify` in the line `BWGL = Solve[gls, vars] //FullSimplify;`. After I removed it, the script only took about 10 seconds.

As said, this was the solution **in my case only**, and I'm still very much interested in more general and substantiated answers.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using //Simplify first as stated above the //FullSimplify can take considerable time vs //Simplify.  Also check your memory status.  If you have been running a session over days your can have memory fragmentation.  I have this problem at times and I reboot and just run Mathematical only.